# Cant able to make WebSocket connection between server(SpringBoot) and iOS

Tags: ios, swift, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

I am trying to make a WebSocket connection between iOS and server(SpringBoot). From the server side, we are using the WebSocket connection like this.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker(URLMapping.WS_SEND);
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes(URLMapping.WS_PREFIX);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/api/v1/transactionSocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

In IOS, I have used [StompClient](https://github.com/ShengHuaWu/StompClient) library for making the WebSocket connection.

```
func makeConnection() {
    let client = StompClient(url: URL(string: "/api/v1/transactionSocket")!)
    client.delegate = self
    client.connect() 
}

func disconnectConnection() {
    client.disconnect()
    print("Disconnecting :\(client)")
}

func stompClientDidConnected(_ client: StompClient) {
    print("Stomp got connected: \(client) .... \(client.isConnected)")
    // client.subscribe("API")
}

func stompClient(_ client: StompClient, didErrorOccurred error: NSError) {
    print("Stomp Error occures \(client)   errror: \(error)")
}

func stompClient(_ client: StompClient, didReceivedData data: Data, fromDestination destination: String) {
    print("Cliemt: \(client)  Data: \(data) destination: \(destination)")
}
```

On running up neither connection is been made nor '*stompClientDidConnected*' delegate method is been called.

I haven't used WebSocket so much. So can't able to understand what the reason is. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your client object is a local variable in makeConnection().  As soon as that method goes out of scope, the client object is going to be de-allocated from memory.

Comment: After declaring client object on top.. i am getting this error log  "Error Domain=WebSocket Code=200 "Invalid HTTP upgrade" in "didErrorOccurred" delegate method

Answer (score 3):

You can use `StopmClientLib` to  make socket connection,also it has the subscribe method.

https://github.com/wrathchaos/StompClientLib

Comment: It worked... At last got a solution. I used this library and forced connection between client and server by appending "/websocket" in the url.